# Type mismatch Integer to Object

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm trying something that should be a simple case of polymorphism. I have a method that returns an object of type ArrayList and am trying to assign an object of type List to the return value of said method. Here's the code:

```
List<Object> inorder = parser.parseInorder();
```

Where I have a parser object to parse an incoming file, and the parseInorder() method returns an

```
ArrayList<Integer>.
```

Eclipse is giving me this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Integer> to List<Object>
```

Comment: And why can't you assign this to a `List<Integer>` ?

Comment: How about: `List<Integer> inorder = parser.parseInorder();` ?

Comment: The declaration really comes earlier in my code, as I may have to assign the List<Object> inorder to a value that returns List<String>.

Comment: So you want to be able to put Integers into the list,  and pull Strings out?  Sounds like something the compiler should stop you from doing.

Comment: Even though Integer is a sub-type of Object, ArrayList<Integer> is not a sub-type of List<Object>. They are totally different types. That's why your compiler is complaining.

Comment: No @David Wallace. I have a List<Object> object that I'll either have to assign to a List<String> object or an ArrayList<Integer> object depending on events at runtime

Comment: It sounds like you should rethink your design.  These two things are not the same, so you can't really have a variable that can reference both.

Comment: Check out this article: https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance. It explains why you can't do what you just did. Essentially, since there's no type information at runtime, there's no way to ensure that there isn't heap pollution. Therefore to avoid this, the compiler will throw an error to prevent you from coercing an ArrayList of Integers to a List of Objects.

Comment: Maybe what you want is a `List<?>` instead of a `List<Object>`.  That's the  correct supertype of `List<String>` and `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Answer (score -1):

Do this :

```
List<Integer> inorder = parser.parseInorder();
```

Comment: I get a new error: `Cannot cast from ArrayList<Integer> to List<Object>`

Comment: @djar It's basically the same error.  You can't convert the types.

Comment: Agree with David.  And if the OP did want a List<Integer>, which he didn't, you wouldn't need the cast.

Comment: @ajb I agreed with you.